# Get a String from an ArrayList. (with numbers)

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an ArrayList of Strings and I want to pull out the element with the largest number.

> Contents of the ArrayList

```
Screaming Mimi:19
WonderWoman:12
Wild Child:25
Titania Ii / Mary Skee:18
Thunderball / Dr. Elio:26
X-man / Nathan Grey:19
Dr. Spectrum / Joseph:6
Captain Britain / Bria:31
Juggernaut / Cain Mark:16
```

> I want to get this:

```
Captain Britain / Bria:31
```

I tried to use a for and an iterator, but I get stuck and i don't know how to get it.

Comment: You are supposed to provide attepted code. Also your question is not very clear.

Comment: Well, what they're trying to say is you need to try solving it first on your own then including your code in your question. :)

Answer (score 0):

Given the following list of items:

```java
      List<String> list = List.of("Screaming Mimi:19",
            "WonderWoman:12",
            "Wild Child:25",
            "Titania Ii / Mary Skee:18",
            "Thunderball / Dr. Elio:26",
            "X-man / Nathan Grey:19",
            "Dr. Spectrum / Joseph:6",
            "Captain Britain / Bria:31",
            "Juggernaut / Cain Mark:16");
```

I would take the following approach:

1. Initialize `max` to smallest possible value
2. Initialize the `selection`
3. Capture the number using `String` methods.
4. Convert it to a binary number use `Integer.parseInt()` and assign to `test`
5. And compare `test` to `max`.  If larger, swap both `string` and `test` with their
   respective values.

```java
      int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
      String selection = "";
      for (String input : list) {
         String strNumb = input.substring(input.indexOf(":") + 1);
         int test = Integer.parseInt(strNumb);
         if (test > max) {
            max = test;
            selection = input;
         }
      }
```

Display the selection

```java
      System.out.println(selection);
```

Answer (score -1):

I believe this is what wou are trying to achieve. Please let me know if you need further assistance.

What it does is take each element of the array list and finds the index of ":", takes the substring of everything after and then converts it into an integer. This integer is compared to the previously believed highest integer using a for iterator to check each element. The highest believed integer is stored as x while it's corresponding String is stored in y.

```
int x=0;
String y="";
for(String i: ArrayList){ //replace "ArrayList" with the name of your array list 
    int z= Integer.parseInt(i.substring(i.indexOf(":") + 1));
    if(z>x){
        x=z;
        y=i;
    }
}
System.out.println(y);
```

Comment: I think people want you to explain what you're doing or they are unhappy that you are not making the person make an attempt. The above does work once you make 2 changes. ":"" should be ":" and String y should be be String y="" to avoid the compile time error/warning on "variable y might not have been initialized."

Comment: @JeremyKahan Thanks for your comment I made said changes and explained my code more thoroughly. Is this better now?

Comment: I think it is. It should compile and work, and it gets back to the original question of how to use the for each loop as an iterator.